# Do hyperlinks wait an Ajax action to complete?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a main page most of the part of the page is loaded as non-Ajax.

A portion of a page is loaded as Ajax action.

If I click any link on the non-Ajax section the on the site,
the page is redirected to new page only after the Ajax action  is completed.

How can I make the redirection  happen with  out completing the Ajax action

Comment: can you show some code and markup that is relevant to your question

Answer (score 1):

you should use asynchronous ajax request, like this:

```
open(method,url,async)
```

the 'async' parameter specifies the request to be asynchronous or not, its a boolean parameter, set it to true like this:

```
open(method,url,true)
```

Comment: i dont think that sync ajax request would stop a link from redirecting

Answer (score 0):

Try use this method

```
function redirect(callback){
    $.ajax({
        data: {somedate},
        complete: function(){
            callback()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: the option "async:true" is default.

Answer (score 0):

```
function redirect(callback){
$.ajax({
    data: {somedate},
    async:true,
    complete: function(){
        callback()
    }
 })
}
```

Comment: I found that there in only a delay in loading the page. The browser is not waiting to complete the ajax request,but there is a delay. What could be reason for the delay?

Comment: what exactly you want?first ajax request execute and then redirect?or without completing the action page redirects?